# Zoom into div iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I have an overlay div over a page faded in with jquery. When I open the website on an iPhone and click on the link to show the overlay with its content, everything is fine. But when I zoom in, the bottom part of the content is gone and I can not scroll to it. I have a fixed height for the content box, but when I make it 100% I can not scroll in it.

CSS:

```
    #overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 2000px;
    left: 0px;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    z-index: 10000;
    margin:auto;
    display:none;
}
#content-box{
    position:relative;
    padding:0px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    width:100%;
    max-width:700px;
    height:650px;
}
#contents{
    width:80%;
    max-width:700px;
    height:590px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Has someone any idea to fix this issue?

Comment: Sounds like the overlay might need `overflow: auto`, but the question is too vague. You need to supply a proper example, including HTML.

Comment: This was a good hint! Now I can see the bottom content! But when I scroll to the position where the content ends before, and I scroll down, I see the content, but the overlay scrolls to top, too. I only want to scroll inside this overlay.. do you have any hints?

Comment: As I say, we need an example, and we can only guess what your code is right now. CSS on its own has no meaning, because we don't know what it applies to.